# How I can convert excel file with nested columns to a dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, data-science

[Edited Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRWnH.png)

I have a table like this. Cell C2 and D2 are merged as a one container, which have data labels. The value of C2 and D2 merged is 01.10.2021. Cells E2 and F2, G2 and H2 are merged also, whilst having data 02.10.2021 and 03.10.2021 respectfully. B4 have city name also, it can change from case to case.

I've tried various solutions, described on the internet, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Share the results what you expected. (ex: an table), that we can help you as possible.

Comment: *Cell C2 and D2 are merged as a one container* are you sure abouth this? in your image they don't look merged at all. Anyways, just unmerge them.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns. Sorry, wrong image. Can you check now?

Comment: Now it makes sense. Please post the code you got and where are you stuck